# How can I mask any element, not only inputs, in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm making an admin dashboard with NextJS and MaterialUI (mui), and I need to mask some values (eg.: phone numbers) that comes from back-end without mask.

I'm using react-input-mask for input elements, but I don't know how to mask any element (for example, a span inside a table cell).

For example, my back-end gives me a phone number like `5511912345678` and a document number like `12345678900`, and I need to display it in a table this way:

| First name | Last name | Phone number | Document |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | +55 (11) 9.1234-5678 | 123.456.789-00 |
| Lorem | Ipsum | +55 (11) 1234-5678 | 234.567.891-00 |

How can I mask that values on a table-cell without an `<input>` element? I assume that will not be possible using react-input-mask, so there's no problem adding another package. I just don't know what package to install to achieve this result.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to share what you tried so far and what problems you did encounter.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a library from NPM or build your own masking function. Here is a naïve implementation of the masking functions. [Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-bkyec3?file=pages%2Findex.js) and following are the important snippets from it.

`digitsExtractor` will return a wrapped object which will help in pulling out digits from the number.

```js
function digitsExtractor(numberString) {
  const digitsInReverse = numberString.split('').reverse();
  const extractDigits = (count = 0) => {
    const digits = [];
    while (count-- > 0) digits.push(digitsInReverse.pop());
    return digits.join('');
  };
  return {
    extractDigits,
    getRemainingDigitsCount: () => digitsInReverse.length,
  };
}
```

`maskPhoneNumber` will mask the phone number

```js
function maskPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  const { extractDigits, getRemainingDigitsCount } =
    digitsExtractor(phoneNumber);

  return `+${extractDigits(2)} (${extractDigits(2)}) ${
    getRemainingDigitsCount() === 8
      ? [extractDigits(4), extractDigits(4)].join('-')
      : getRemainingDigitsCount() === 9
      ? `${extractDigits(1)}.${extractDigits(4)}-${extractDigits(4)}`
      : ''
  }`;
}
```

`maskDocumentNumber` will mask the document number

```js
function maskDocumentNumber(documentNumber) {
  const { extractDigits } = digitsExtractor(documentNumber);

  return [
    [extractDigits(3), extractDigits(3), extractDigits(3)].join('.'),
    extractDigits(2),
  ].join('-');
}
```

You can make it more generic based on your requirements.